# Oracle Database Password security from developer in C# Applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 application in C# with Oracle 11g Database.
1: C# desktop application with connection class to connect to database with connection string.
2: ASP.NET C# web application with connection class to connect to database with connection string.
3: MVC4 Web application. using entity framework and saves db password in web.config

We are asked to work with test database and we don't have live database access. We have a DBA who is managing database. Need some professional Advise on below questions.

**Q1:** Professional way of writing connection string including all securities?

**Q2:** Is is possible to have one centralized connection string(desktop app is also on same LAN network)?

**Q3:** Entity Data Model create connection string in web.config so I wan to change location of connection string means Entity Data Model object use my given connection string to connect to db?

**Q4:** DBA says i will change database password and your all application's password should be automatically changed, so he is asking me to tell him the way or make my applications in a way to achieve that, Is it possible?

Comment: A1: Cant understand question; A2,A3,A4: yes

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would store your connection string in web.config, and have the EntityFramework or other methods pull the connection string from that location. This would require each application to have the connection string listed in it, but it is a central location. We always use Windows authentication for our Oracle connections (which you should probably be doing as well). In that case our connection string is pretty simple, something like:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Connection" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=DevDB;USER ID=/&quot" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: But web.config file is not secure in my case, i need some other way to store and safe connection string or may be encrypted.

Comment: My point was that the connection doesn't need to be secure. All that is in it is the name of the database connection, the username and password are all using Windows authentication. Web.config is only moderately less secure than putting it in code, since its very easy to ruin a disassembler to see the string.